# Connect list items to library items

Tags: list, document-library

I need a way to establish many-to-many relationships between items in a list (fieldnotes) and documents in a library (evidence). The main challenge is finding a way to make data entry in this set-up as user-friendly as possible. For various reasons, using the standard attachment functionality is not an option.

Typically, a user of our knowledge base will be entering fieldnote metadata and, as part of that, will want to upload one or more new pieces of evidence (documents) and/or connect the fieldnote to existing evidence.

Since my end users are not very used to working with SharePoint, I would like them to be able to do all this in a single form.

Please note that documents in the evidence library would not need to have fieldnotes associated with them; they should also be able to exist in their own right.

In addition to all of the above, I have no access to SP Designer...

All help would be much appreciated!

Niels

Comment: multi lookup column?